# How to create an AJAX-working Website?

Tags: c#, ajax, controls, toolkit

I am using VS 2005 (c#) and I installed lately the AJAX-ToolKit, so now I have ajax controls in my toolbox.

I have no AJAX-Enabled template. Can you guide me how can I create and config my empty website so AJAX will work on it? because I followed a tutorial and created one control but I got some errors because I dont know how to configure my website for using these controls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should install ASP.NET Ajax 1.0, that is the version for ASP.NET 2.0

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks you sloved my problem :)
I installed this and installed an older virsion of AJAX and its works all fine. Thank!!

Answer (score -1):

W3C has some good tutorials [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

[Here](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/) is another good site.

Comment: The W3C are an organization that writes standards. W3Schools are an organization that slaps adverts over tutorials that vary in quality from "Alright" to "Awful bastions of security hole infested horror" and get too much reflected glory from having two letters in their name matching two letters of the W3C. Their first example of Ajax fails by using a global which ensures that multiple requests going off at once will overwrite each other.

Comment: The second tutorial loses points for failing to spell JavaScript correctly (and not even getting it wrong in a consistent way) and claiming that the "great" thing about Ajax is that you don't have to have a form … which isn't great at all: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build